# ASP.NET webforms maintain List<string> across postbacks

Tags: asp.net, list, viewstate, session-variables

Hello I have a small `List<string>` that I want to maintain across postbacks on only ONE page. The List will not contain more than 10 items, with each item being 40 chars max (no sensitive data).

I know that similar questions have been asked, but I am somewhat ambivalent between storing this in `ViewState` or `Session`. I've heard that even small string values can cause the ViewState value to increase quite largely in size. I would like to iterate through the List and use Linq to query it, but would I be better off using a `string[]` array, and would this List (of humble size) be okay to store in `ViewState` or should I be storing it in `Session`? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing things in ViewState isn't a terrible idea if you don't abuse it. If the list is small and it only makes sense on one page, then go for it.

Just remember ViewState can be tampered with, so if you don't want the client to know about it, then you are golden. Otherwise store it in Session.

Comment: Hey Josh, thanks for that. Is there any compelling reason to store it in `Session`?

Comment: This probably is only one of 2 things in my entire application that I'm purposefully wanting to store in ViewState.

Comment: @maGz - Only if you want it to persist across the entire session, or have access to it in different pages. I tend to avoid using session as much as possible simply because it can make scaling more difficult if you are heavily dependent on session. Like for instance getting bounced to a different server in a web farm. If it only exists for a single page, then ViewState is your best bet. Again, just don't abuse it. Large ViewState is it's own form of evil.

Answer (score 2):

I would be more concerned about the scope of this `List<>`.  If it's limited only to this single page, then I think it is perfectly acceptable to use the `ViewState`; that's exactly what it was meant for.

However if you need to persist this across multiple pages, then it would make more sense to evaluate `Session` or `Cache`.

I would also keep in mind if the list is different for each user, or if it could be shared amongst multiple users.  In that case I would lean towards `Cache`.

Finally, and I'll probably be downvoted into oblivion on this one, but you could also look at the option of storing the `ViewState` in the server-side memory using the [SessionPageStatePersister](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.sessionpagestatepersister.aspx)  class.

Good luck!

Comment: all info helps in my learning so I'll +1 to u! I don't need it persisted across multiple pages (in fact I'd prefer if the data wasn't available anywhere else, although I am clearing all Session vars `OnLoggedOut` using `Session.Abandon()`). It will change poer user, as I basically want to keep track of the filenames of photos uploaded by users...the thing is that users can also choose to omit certain photos that they have already uploaded, and also provide me a way to check if they are not uploading more than 10 photos.